# Query to show both tagged and Userstory tagged defects in custom grid

Tags: rally

I am trying to show both defects tagged with a certain tag "Project: Name" and defects who's userstory is tagged with the same name. I've created the below but what the first one results is only defects with userstories with the tag being displayed. The second works for defects that have been tagged but does not follow the requirement. What needs to be fixed?

**1. Query Missing Tagged Defects**

```
(((Tags.Name contains "Project: Name") OR (Requirement.Tags.Name contains "Project: Name")) AND (State < Closed))
```

**2. Query include Tagged Defects**

```
((Tags.Name contains "Project: Name")  AND (State < "Closed"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is a known bug. Querying on Tags using OR doesn't return the correct results.

```
((Tags.Name contains "tagX")OR(Requirement.Tags.Name contains "tagX"))
```

returns only defects that meet `(Requirement.Tags.Name contains "tagX")` but if I limit my query to `(Tags.Name contains "tagX")` it also returns correct results.

Using `=` operator instead of `contains` does not make a difference.

It's expected to be addressed  in the future, but I am afraid there is no ETA.